# How to store each output of a for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to store each output, from 1 to 1000, as a row.

So far I have:

```
n<-1000
for(n in 1:n) {
  count <- 0
  check <- ifelse(n>1, TRUE, FALSE)
  while(check) {
    if (n%%2==1) {
      n=3*n+1
    } else {
      n=n/2
    }
    count=count+1
    check<- ifelse(n>1, TRUE, FALSE)}
  print(count)
}
```

But don't know how to save each number that comes out because count is overwritten each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to store the `count` as a vector.

In this code, an empty vector `result_vector` was created before the for loop.

Instead of `print(count)`, you can append `count` to `result_vector`.

```
n<-1000
result_vector <- c()
for(n in 1:n) {
  count<-0
  check<- ifelse(n>1, TRUE, FALSE)
  while(check) {
    if (n%%2==1) {n=3*n+1
    } else {n=n/2}
    count=count+1
    check<- ifelse(n>1, TRUE, FALSE)}
  result_vector <- c(result_vector, count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the 'purrr' map functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 1000

# use the 'map' functions in 'purrr' to create a vector instead
# of extending the vector in the loop
result_vector <- map_dbl(1:n, ~ {
  n <- .x  # save parameter in 'n' to keep code the same
  count <- 0
  check <- if (n > 1)
    TRUE
  else
    FALSE
  while (check) {
    if (n %% 2 == 1) {
      n = 3 * n + 1
    } else {
      n = n / 2
    }
    count = count + 1
    check <- if (n > 1)
      TRUE
    else
      FALSE
  }
  count
})
```